# Child component is not updating parent's state in React.js functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders a child component. The child component manages its own state, and I am trying to pass the updated state to the parent, using a callback, to no success. I have tried for hours to identify the problem but haven't been able to figure it out. My parent component is this (without imports):

```
const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_CATEGORY':
      return {
        category: action.category
      };

    default:
      return state;  
  }
};


function LogService() {
  
   const initialFormState = 
   {
    category: ''   
   };

   const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, initialFormState);

   const getCategoryState = useCallback(category => {
    dispatch({
      action: 'SET_CATEGORY',
      category: category
    }, []);
  } 
  );

    
  
  const submitHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();    
    console.log(formState);      
  };  
    
   
  return (

    <>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>        
        <CategoryOne sendState={getCategoryState} />        
        <button>send</button>
      </form>    
    </>

  );

};

export default LogService;
```

And this is my child component:

```
const selectionReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'DISPLAY_SELECTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        selectionIsVisible: true
      };
    case 'LOG_SELECTION':
      return {
        ...state,
        category: action.category,
        selectionIsVisible: false        
      }  

    default:
      return state;  
  }
};

function CategoryOne(props) {
  
    
  const [selectionState, dispatch] = useReducer(selectionReducer, {});

  
  const { category } = selectionState;
  const { sendState } = props;
  
  
  useEffect(() => {
    sendState(category);    
  }, [category, sendState])  
  
  const displaySelectionHandler = event => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'DISPLAY_SELECTION'
    });
  };

  const selectCategoryHandler = event => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'LOG_SELECTION',
      category: event.target.id
    });
    
  };

    
  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">          
        <div className={`options-container ${selectionState.selectionIsVisible && 'active'}`}>          
          <div className="option">
            <input className="radio" type="radio" id="One" name="category"  onChange={selectCategoryHandler} />
            
          </div>
          <div className="option">
            <input className="radio" type="radio" id="Two" name="category" onChange={selectCategoryHandler} />
            
          </div>
          <div className="option">
            <input className="radio" type="radio" id="Three" name="category" onChange={selectCategoryHandler} />
            
          </div>
          <div className="option">
            <input className="radio" type="radio" id="Four" name="category" onChange={selectCategoryHandler} />
            
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="selected" id="category" onClick={displaySelectionHandler}>
          Category
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );  
  
};

export default CategoryOne;
```

I am not getting Errors, just a Warning:

```
React Hook useCallback does nothing when called with only one argument. Did you forget to pass an array of dependencies?
```

I don't understand that warning, I do have an array of dependencies. other than that, selectionIsVisible: true (in the 'DISPLAY_SELECTION' action) works, but selectionIsVisible: false (in the 'LOG_SELECTION' action).

Could someone please help me out? I am very frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

Because use put `[]` wrong place. Just update like this:

```
  const getCategoryState = useCallback((category) => {
    dispatch({
      action: "SET_CATEGORY",
      category: category,
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks Viet!!! Unfortunately, state is still not getting updated :/